# How to extract the information from pan card and save it in a excel column in ui path

Tags: rpa, uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot

I need to extract the information from pan card which is in pdf format and store it in a excel with seperate columns like name, fathers name and pan number in different columns . Can anyone help me on this

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have used read pdf with OCR and read the pdf then used excel application scope and stored in excel which is stored in a single cell all the details of the pan card